# Make a span item editable?

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple web app, in one part of it I want the user to be able to edit the text put up by me on the screen. The text is currently contained in a `<span>` element.

How is it possible?

Comment: Is there any point in the page where JavaScript would be necessary, such as clicking a button to make the content editable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set `contenteditable` attribute as `true`

```
<span contenteditable="true">edit</span>
```

or simply add `contenteditable` only

```
<span contenteditable>edit</span>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Ggf6W/)

Answer (score 8):

you can use `contenteditable` for that

```
<span contenteditable> you can edit this text </span>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fFXY5/)

Comment: [Pretty well supported too - via caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable)